How to properly reference SAPUI5 components deployed on BTP Cloud Foundry for embed in another Components (reuse component)
While developing Fiori applications on SAP BTP I came across the same issue over and over again. How do we do to embed other components that are deployed separately in the same CF Space.
Here is a discussion about how to do it on a On-premise scenario (BSP Applications) and also on a Neo environment.
There is also the official documentation about app descriptor (manifest) and how to nest components. None of these docs explains how to address component embedding/nesting/reusing in a SAP BTP Cloud Foundry scenario.
Whenever I try to use componentUsage as described in the docs, it tries to load the component from "/resources/namespace/of/my/component". And this route refers directly to SAPUI5 cdn as defined in xs-app.json and ui5.yaml configuration files.
Have anyone ever did it successfully?

When I think of reuse components immediately the spreadsheet importer comes to mind.
Of course in their docs the have a section on how to integrate this component in a BTP environment, together with a full sample app.
They also recommend these blog posts for further reading:

Components in same space
Components in different spaces

